# About symbolic package error for Octave 4.2.1

Tags: matlab, octave

I import symbolic package to octave v.4.2.1.

And then install python-2.7.14 with sympy-1.1.1.tar.gz package.

Now I can normally use the function of symbolic, except "syms" can not be used.

My operating system is win10. Before, I use win 7 can normally use "syms" function, but win 10 can't.

How can I normally use "syms"?

I'm not sure it be a bug in win10.

Thanks.

[Figfure1: syms function show the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfZg3.png)

[Figfure2: Python package installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEgEh.png)

Comment: From octave I am using the package `symbolic` V2.6.0 under windows 7. Maybe this is a hint for a possible solution.

Comment: Have you installed following the install instructions (from what I've read above apparently not) https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy and https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/wiki/Notes-on-Windows-installation

Comment: Hi Georg, But my notebook can't install win7.

Comment: Hi Andy, it a good information for me. Now, I can run "syms" in a specific directory,  but the other directory does not work. I don't know why the "sym" and "poly2sym" can run in other directory, but "syms" can't.